# printing list in python after a function

Tags: python, string, list, printing

I have been trying to print the results of a function that happen to be in a list. If this doesn't make sense.

In `print_long.py`, define a Python function `print_long(list)` that takes a list of strings called list and prints out each string in list that has a length greater than or equal to 6.

That is the original question. I tried doing

```
def print_long(list):  
    for i in print_long(list):  
        if len(list) > 6:  
            print (i)  
        else:  
            return None
```

but that is clearly wrong since it infinitely loops it. Or it seems to appear to do that.
help.

Comment: Don't use 'list' as a variable name. It's the name of an internally used type

Comment: Do you understand that the function recurses? Why do you calculate length of a list rather than length of the list element?

Comment: `for x in mylist: print x`

Comment: Are you have list of lists of lists...: [1 ,2 ,[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, ...], ...], ...] ?

Answer (score 3):

Your code appears to be a recursive call with no base (terminating) condition. That is, when you first call `print_long()` you are immediately calling `print_long()`, which calls `print_long()` ad infinitum.

The code you were probably attempting is something like:

```
def greater_than(mylist, n):
    for item in mylist:
        if len(item) > n:
            print item

mylist = ["hello", "foo", "bar", "testing", "world"]
greater_than(mylist, 4) # Prints: hello, testing, world
```

Or, more simply:

```
mylist = ["hello", . . ., "world"] # Same as above
n = 4
[x for x in mylist if len(x) > n] # ['hello', 'testing', 'world']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
def print_long(in_list):   # define your function
    for i in in_list:      # loop over the input list
        if len(i) > 6:     # test the length of the elements
            print (i)      # if true print it out
        else:              # you don't need this else, as you really just want
            pass           # to do nothing if len(i) < 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Name your parameter something other than list. Jonathon Reinhart gave a good suggestion: mylist. 
The other code examples above also provide good suggestions for writing your for loop better:

```
for i in mylist:
```

You might also need to change the len() to => 6.

```
if len(i) >= 6
```

From what you wrote, it look says, "prints out each string in list that has a length greater than or equal to 6." So you'll need the equal to make sure you capture lengths equal to 6

Answer (score 1):

A short one:

```
def print_greater_or_equal_than(mylist, n):
  print '\n'.join(filter(lambda i: len(i) >= n, mylist))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a recursive call to your function without reducing your list input, first. Therefore, it will continue to make recursive calls to infinity.

To avoid the infinite stack of recursion, print the item in the list & remove it before recursing :

```
def print_long(list): 
    i = list.pop(0)
    if len(list) > 6:  
        print (i)  
    else:  
        return None
    if len(list):
        print_long(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, list is a reserved keyword in Python, so don't use it as a parameter or variable name. I usually use `lst`. Anyway, there are a few other issues to work out here.

```
def print_long(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if len(i) >= 6:
            print i

print_long(['foo','bar','hello','johnny'])
```

Before, you were trying to iterate through your function:

```
for i in print_long(lst)
```

This is incorrect, you simply want to iterate through the list, as shown in the first example above. A more pythonic way of achieving the result you are looking for is:

```
print ' '.join([i for i in lst if len(i) >= 6])
```

Look up [Python list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)s if you don't understand.